# adding a simple notification system in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, notifications, social-networking, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a simple social media type application where users can add each other as friends and can comment on there friend's post. What I wanna do now is to inform a user whenever their friend add a comment on their post. I don't want a real time notification system i prefer a very simple system. Is their any gem available. Can anyone help me with by suggesting how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Rails ecosystem kind of lacks a good gem to do that...

Trying to solve this problematic, we just released a gem to do that. We called it [Wupee](https://github.com/sleede/wupee)

Right now, it is quite simple but already fills our needs at [Sleede](http://www.sleede.com/) and we plan to improve it and make it more powerfull as we get more feedbacks. Feel free to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can create notification log table in database, after comment or post you can store log in notification and set one attribute is_readed for to knw user was readed or not notification.
And as per is_readed attribute you can filter notification database to show unreaded notification 
Also you can do more things as per your requirements through notification logs table and if you think its take more space to store in database then no problem you can delete old notification logs as per certain period or after user read.